# ¿Por qué se muestran así las tabs cuando está en modo horizontal?

Tags: android

Tengo solo dos Tabs, en modo vertical se muestra correctamente, pero en modo horizontal, no se ajusta al tamaño de la pantalla. Pero cuando pongo 3 o más tabs se si ajusta a la pantalla en modo horizontal.
Este es mi código XML
[image: cuando tengo solo 2 tabs]
[image: cuando tengo mas de 2 tabs]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTabsOpciones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed">
```

Comment: Añade la propiedad app:tabMaxWidth="0dp", puedes ver la solución aquí
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843775/tab-not-taking-full-width-on-tablet-device-using-android-support-design-widget

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se requiere generalmente es lo que tratas de evitar que es distribuir los tabs uniformemente a lo ancho de la pantalla y lo cual se realiza mediante:

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

o mediante:

```
app:tabGravity="fill"
```

en tu caso entonces elimina esta propiedad:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTabsOpciones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:tabMode="fixed">
```